# Safari browser is loosing scroll position when changing scroll-snap-type or scroll-snap-align

Tags: javascript, safari, scroll-snap

No matter if I change the scroll-snap-type or the scroll-snap-align, Safari looses the scroll position and starts from first scroll-snap element. This problem can be easily reproduced in the scroll example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type. Just switch to scroll-snap-type: mandatory, scroll to 2nd or 3rd element. Then switch to scroll-snap-type: none and back again to scroll-snap-type: mandatory. In all browsers the scroll position stays the same, in Safari it starts again from 0.

Why do I need this? I am using a scroll animation that changes the scrollTop position. When using scroll-snap in Safari the animation does not work e.g. when click on a navigation link to scroll to another section. So my idea was to turn scroll-snap off when using a navigation link and turn it on again when done. Works fine in all browsers, leads to described problem in Safari. I also tried to change the scroll-snap-align instead, but its the same.

Did someone experience the same problem? Did you find a workaround / solution?

Comment: The issue does not persist in iOS 15 but there should definitely be a fix for versions below 15

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here - may I ask if you have found a solution? Mine is to simply disable scroll-snapping for Safari, with the impact of less user-comfort ... written in less:

```
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; // vertical scroll-snap
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { // detect Safari
    scroll-snap-type: unset;
}
```

Comment: In the end I turned off scroll snapping in Javascript before the scroll animation starts and turned it on again when scroll animation ends. I would consider this more as a workaround than a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. What finally worked for me was to set `overflow: hidden` on the element while you're changing the `scroll-snap-type`. This prevents the container from being manually scrolled, and also seems to prevent Safari from resetting the scroll position. Once the scroll animation is complete, you can restore the `scroll-snap-type` and remove `overflow: hidden`.

I did this by creating a new class:

```
.disable-snapping
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: none;
```

And the exact steps that worked for me are:

1. Before the scroll animation starts, add the `disable-snapping` class to the scrollable container.
2. Do the scroll animation.
3. Once the animation is complete, remove the `disable-snapping` class.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same, because I wanted to implement dragging. I decided to lose the dragging functionality. I fixed your problem with `scroll-behavior: smooth;` and used anchor links.

You can find my code here: https://codepen.io/joosts/pen/MWJBPgo?editors=0110

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered the same problem. Very annoying.. But resetting the scroll position after re-enabling the scroll-snap behavior works surprisingly well.

```js
const onDragEnd = () => {
    const scroller = $('.scroll-container');
    const scrollLeft = scroller.scrollLeft();
    scroller.removeClass('drag-in-progress'); // this class disabled scroll-snapping
    requestAnimationFrame(() => scroller.scrollLeft(scrollLeft));
};
```